# Calculate the series: $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ using dirichlet's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

This question was in my exam:

Calculate the series: $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$.

I answered wrong and the teacher noted:  `"You should use dirichlet's theorem"`.

I know my question is a bit general,

but can you please explain me how should I have solved this sum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By solve do you finding the actual limit of this series, or just showing whether or not it is convergent?

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem, as I understand it, is a test for convergence (that is easily applicable here). Computing the value of the stated series is difficult to do from scratch.

Comment: Or is it Dirichlet's theorem from the theory of Fourier series?

Comment: It does not look clear to me what "Dirichlet's theorem" your teacher is referring to (Dirichlet's test? Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions?), neither I would say that this is a "linear algebra" question.

Answer (score 6):

By absolute convergence you can simply write:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n \text{ even}}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{1}{n^2}=2\cdot\sum_{n \text{ even}}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{2}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$
Have a look at [this hot question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2), too.

Comment: Elegant answer +1)

Answer (score 3):

Jack's answer is perfectly all right.

If you want to use Dirichlet's theorem from the theory of Fourier series, consider the $2\pi$-periodic function $f$ such that $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-\pi,\pi)$.